# Python 2.7: Programa não roda

Tags: python

Olá,
Meu programa não está mais rodando, antes funcionava normalmente mas depois simplesmente não funciona. Verifiquei que o programa não passa da linha  "reload(sys)".

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
from gtts import gTTS as gtts
import sys
reload(sys);
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8');

def audio_br(words, mp3name, language="pt"):
  teste= gtts(text=words,lang=language);
  teste.save("%s.mp3" % mp3name);

audio_br("Segundo ao portal New York times sobre política no Brazil temos","padrão_");
audio_br("Segundo ao portal Catraca Livre sobre tecnologia temos","padrão_a");
audio_br("Segundo ao portal Partiu Intercâmbio sobre bolsas de estudos temos","padrão_b");
audio_br("Segundo ao portal Estudar Fora sobre bolsas de estudos temos","padrão_c");
```

Comment: Como assim "não roda"? Responda as perguntas na ordem e não deixe de responder nenhuma: 1 - Ocorre algum erro? 2 - Ou simplesmente ele abre no editor de texto? 3 - É linux ou Windows? ... Espero 3 respostas para poder conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: E uma possível quarta pergunta: o que mudou de quando funcionava para quando parou de funcionar? O que mudou no código? O que mudou no computador? O que instalou a mais? O que desinstalou? Mudou de computador? Mudou a versão do Python?

Comment: 1) O programa simplesmente não roda, basicamente eu testei alguns prints na tela e só é mostrado o print que vem antes do reload. Em suma não aparece nada na tela e nem gera os arquivos mp3.

Comment: 1)O programa não mostra nenhum erro, porém não cria os mp3. Eu gerei alguns prints na tela e só eram mostrado aqueles que vinham antes do reload.
2) Ele abre o shell não roda nada
3) windows
4) não instalei nem mudei nada, apenas estava testando pra ver como seriam gerados os arquivos mp3. No caso se eu não usar isso (tornar pra utf-8) dá algum erro de encode ascii

Comment: E qual a função do `reload` nesse código?

Comment: basicamente pra não dar erro de encode quando eu for fazer os audios .mp3 utilizando o gtts

Comment: 4) Como você esta rodando este problema, duplo clique ou pelo terminal? Tente executar no terminal e pega o erro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss creio que seja essa a função do `reload` no script dele: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628350/1518921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho exatamente o Python 2.7 instalado na minha máquina, **os pontos e virgula não afetou o funcionamento**, o único erro que tive foi:

> No module named gtts

Isto porque eu não tinha o módulo instalado, então instalei ele via `pip` no cmd (estou usando Windows):

```
pip install gTTS
```

o resultado foi:

[image: resultado]

Veja os possíveis erros

### Os arquivos estão sendo salvos em outra pasta

O teu script se for executado por exemplo:

```
 c:\Users\user> python c:\exemplos\python\script.py
```

Vai salvar os `.mp3` na pasta `c:\Users\user` e não na pasta `c:\exemplos\python`

Ou assim (unix-like):

```
 eu@debian:~$ python /home/usuario/exemplos/python/script.py
```

Vai salvar os `.mp3` na pasta `/home/[usuario]` (`~$` indica a `home` do usuário) e não na pasta `/home/usuario/exemplos/python`

Então ele salva a partir de onde executou.

### Falta de permissão de escrita

Talvez o local aonde esteja tentando salvar os arquivos não tenha permissão de escrita, depende muito de onde esta tentando executar e o sistema operacional, se o teu `.py` estiver por exemplo na pasta `c:\Programs and Files` não irá gravar os `.mp3` a não ser que tenha modo administrativo, claro que se você estiver tentando executar a partir dessa pasta.

### Codificação

Se o teu `.py` estiver salvo com uma codificação diferente de `utf-8` pode ser que ele cause este erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/n.py", line 12, in <module>
    audio_br("Segundo ao portal New York times sobre polÝtica no Brazil temos","
padrÒo_");
  File "tests/n.py", line 9, in audio_br
    teste= gtts(text=words,lang=language);
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", l
ine 94, in __init__
    if self._len(text) <= self.MAX_CHARS:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", l
ine 154, in _len
    return len(text.decode('utf8'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16,
 in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 42: invalid
continuation byte
```

Isto porque a lib aparentemente trabalha com utf-8.